# With a model that belongs_to two models. Why can I create an object with no ID in the Rails console, but will rollback with a spec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Rails 5 app**

Less of a "how to" question and more of a, "did I do anything wrong?" I have a simple set up of Users, Forums, and Comments.

Users can create `forum`s and make `post`s on `forum`s. I am trying to set it up so that a `post` cannot be created unless it has a `forum_id` to assign it.

Schema:

```
  create_table "forums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_forums_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "forum_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["forum_id"], name: "index_posts_on_forum_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    ...
    #Devise stuff removed for brevity.
    ...
  end

  add_foreign_key "posts", "forums"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "users"
end
```

My models:

```
#User model.
has_many :forums
has_many :posts

#Forum model.
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts

#Post model.
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :forum
```

Now, If I try to run my spec test like so:

```
@user  = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
@forum = FactoryGirl.create(:forum, user: @user)
@user.posts.create!(title: "test title", description: "test description")
```

It will return with a Fail:

```
 Failure/Error: @user.posts.create!(title: "test title", description: "test description")

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Forum must exist
```

Which is the correct result I want. However, I noticed while going into my Rails Console that it will allow me to create a `post` without an ID:

```
2.3.0 :006 > u.posts.create!(title: "test title", description: "test description")
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "test title"], ["description", "test description"], ["user_id", 3], ["created_at", 2016-10-28 20:47:10 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-28 20:47:10 UTC]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Post id: 7, title: "test title", description: "test description", user_id: 3, forum_id: nil, created_at: "2016-10-28 20:47:10", updated_at: "2016-10-28 20:47:10">
```

Why is it not rolling back with a failure? Do I not have everything set up correct and can this come back to bite me later on?

Comment: do you have a validation in your post model? like `belongs_to :forum, required: true`

Comment: No, it just says `belongs_to :forum`. There is no `required: true`. I was under the assumption that since it belong to something, it was required to include it. After all, I cannot create a `post` with a missing `forum_id` on a spec test. Inside the console, I can.

Comment: maybe the factory girl default is to require associated records. But I don't think that's true in Rails.

Comment: Check if after `@user  = FactoryGirl.create(:user)` the @user is valid and persited in DB. Try `@user.persisted?` and `@user.valid?`

Comment: @chumakoff, everything is valid and persisted after creating them with FactoryGirl inside the spec test. A post with no `forum_id` will return with an error inside the spec test (or `byebug` inside the spec test). But, with plain Rails console, I can create.

@maxpleaner, yeah I've tried both methods. Using factories to create objects and manually creating them as well. It doesn't change the output.

Comment: Do you have any validation that relates to `forum` or `forum_id` in any of the 3 models?

Comment: @chumakoff, no, everything I posted in this question relating to the models is what I have with the exception of minimum lengths of characters in the field and doesn't relate to the validation error I'm getting. It's simply a `belongs_to` or `has_many` in all my models. there is no explicit validation for IDs. I expect the validation error I got in my spec test but I don't understand why I'm allowed to create `Post`s with no `forum_id` attached to it in the rails console. I feel I have a hole somewhere that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I do want to add a comment that this is a Rails 5 app. Which, after research explains that in Rails 5. belongs_to validations are required by default.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you link tables in Rails, the correlating `owner_id` is not required. Would recommend putting a validation in your Post model:

```
# in Post.rb

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :forum

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :forum_id, presence: true

  # if you want to go a step further
  validates :user_id, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :forum_id, numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Comment: I thought that in Rails 5, belongs_to validations were on by default?

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937

I'll give this a try, but it's still a bit of a concern.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Definitely running Rails 4. Should've checked before responding. Good luck!